# Operator changed to int during infix to postfix conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion, stack, queue

```
private DSAQueue parseInfixToPostfix(String equation) {
        String result = "";
        char operator = ' ';
        DSAStack stack = new DSAStack();
        DSAQueue queue = new DSACircular();

        for (int i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++) {
            char c = equation.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                result += c;
            }

            else if (c == '(') {
                stack.push(c);
            }

            else if (c == ')') {
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.top() != '(') {
                    result += stack.pop();
                }

                if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.top() != '(') {
                    result = "Invalid expression";
                }

                else {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }

            else { //when meets operator
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && (precedenceOf(c) <= precedenceOf((char) stack.top()))) {
                    if (stack.top() == '(') {
                        result = "Invalid expression";
                    }
                    result += stack.pop();
                }
                stack.push(c);
            }
        }

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            if (stack.top() == '(') {
                result = "Invalid";
            }
            result += stack.pop();
        }
        queue.enqueue(result);
        return queue;
    }
```

Above is my code for converting infix to postfix. The example i used is "4+2" and what i got is:

```
Pushed: 43
Popped: 43
Enqueued: 4243
```

i dont know why it automatically converted "+" to 43, but i want to store the operator as the operator like "+" in the queue. Is it possible? Or is there an error? because i cant find out what the error is. thank you

Comment: ASCII code of '+' is 43. You store the ASCII code of the operator. You can convert it to char before printing.

Comment: so you mean at the enqueue part just cast it to char?